# Where is the kill switch in Cyberghost?

Tags: vpn, internet-connection

I am using Cyberghost 6 on a Windows 10 machine, and I've upgraded to a premium plus account. This vpn service is praised by many online reviews and many of them say that it provides a kill switch. However, I've searched a lot in the settings for this switch but couldn't find it. Anyone can help with that ? After all, what is a vpn if it wasn't for the kill switch.

Comment: Its an automatic switch, if your connection drops the kill switch activates.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article, the kill switch for Cyber Ghost is automatically enabled with no way to disable it.

https://thebestvpn.uk/articles-and-guides/learn-and-win/vpn-kill-switch/

Answer (score 1):

There is no kill switch, you can easily test it yourself. Just make a ping to google, then close cyberghost.exe in the task manager and you will see that there is no interruption, also your network icon is not showing that it is disconnected. Cyberghost is NOT safe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I just realized that. I am located in India with very few options as this country will ruin it for all the countries in the world. All VPNs and emails that don't give away everything including email content, ipaddress, card details, bitcoin accounts, device information in detail cannot operate here in this shithole.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1174853)

Answer (score 1):

To kill a task or a process called cyberghost means nothing because the vpn don't need this elements to work ... on Linux you don't have something active and called cyberghost but the vpn works though ...
A least check your IP address after killing the cyberghost.exe ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of a Kill Switch is, for the most important example I need it for; to prevent you from being caught torrenting on your normal unsecured IP.
   If the VPN isn't working or blacks out temporarily instead of continuing to torrent your connection stops totally. This is so you will never be unprotected as long as you're using Cyberghost. You paid frigging $ so you'd never be caught, whatever you were doing, Torrenting,  Hacking the USA Democratic National Committee so Republicans can win, without a kill switch you can still be easily caught doing so, and be hauled in front of Mueller's team.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

As was mentioned.. Open a browser or ping to the net.. Will be no interruption in your service when you kill cyberghost. I believe it's unsafe also and canceled my sub within just 24 hours of using it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1109197)